When usg ffmpeg to convert from .mp4 to .avi, how do I get the .avi files to contain the correct (trimmed) frames from the .mp4?
I am using ffmpeg to convert a batch of .mp4 videos to the .avi format from the command line. The .mp4 videos are all trimmed videos that are sub-videos of a longer video. I have basically segmented the longer video into small, non-overlapping chunks (or maybe with a couple milliseconds of overlap), and I want to convert all of these smaller chunks (.mp4) to .avi. However, I am running into an issue: the .avi files all contain a some additional frames at the beginning of each video which I explicitly trimmed in the .mp4 videos. I'm not sure what exactly is causing this problem or how to solve it. I suspect that there is some inconsistency in the frame rate when converting the videos, but I could be wrong.
I have tried using the following commands:
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg  -i "$file" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "${file%.mp4}.avi"; done
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg  -i "$file" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -fps_mode 2 "${file%.mp4}.avi"; done
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg  -i "$file" -c:v copy -c:a copy -fps_mode 2 "${file%.mp4}.avi"; done
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg  -i "$file" -c:v copy -c:a copy -fps_mode 1 "${file%.mp4}.avi"; done
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v copy -c:a copy "${file%.mp4}.avi"; done     
all to no avail. How can I solve this issue such that only the frames in the trimmed .mp4 video are processed in the resulting .avi?

I may have found a solution to this. I just modified the frame rate of the output to match the frame rate of the input. In this case, the frame rate is encoded at 25 fps. Something like this:
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -r 25 "${file%.mp4}.avi"; done
